# Writing a tokenizer, where to begin?

Tags: c++, css, tokenize

I'm trying to write a tokenizer for CSS in C++, but I have no idea how to write a tokenizer. I know that it should be greedy, reading as much input as possible, for each token, and in theory I know how I could put that in code.

I have looked at Boost.Tokenizer, and it seems nice, but it doesn't help me whatsoever. It sure is a nice wrapper for a tokenizer, but the problem lies in writing the token splitter, the TokenizerFunction in Boost terms.

I have no idea how to write this tokenizer, are there any "neat" ways of doing it, like something that closely resembles [the syntax itself](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#tokenization)?

Please note, I'm not looking for a parser! My application doesn't need to be able to understand CSS, just read a CSS file to a general internal tokenized format, process some things and output again.

Comment: Note that the end-of-file rules make tokenizing CSS using an off-the-shelf tokenizer ... interesting.  Assuming it's possible at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a "correct" lexer and/or parser is more difficult than you might think. And it can get ugly when you start dealing with weird corner cases.

My best suggestion is to invest some time in learning a proper lexer/parser system. CSS should be a fairly easy language to implement, and then you will have acquired an amazingly powerful tool you can use for all sorts of future projects.

I'm an Old Fart® and I use lex/yacc (or things that use the same syntax) for this type of project. I first learned to use them back in the early 80's and it has returned the effort to learn them many, many times over.

BTW, if you have anything approaching a BNF of the language, lex/yacc can be laughably easy to work with.

Comment: Lex and Yacc still the easiest way to do this.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Lex&Yacc, is it a library, a language or?

Comment: @nightcracker Google Google Google!

Comment: @Henry: I am, but I am really confused. A snippet of code is at the wikipedia page, but it seems to be C mixed with something that is supposedly lex.

Comment: @nightcracker - from the wikipedia page you mention: "Lex reads an input stream specifying the lexical analyzer and outputs source code implementing the lexer in the C programming language." Seems pretty clear...

Comment: @Henry: Woops, read over that :) This page clarifies a lot though: http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~lgao/teaching/flex.html.

Comment: @nightcracker: Note that there are a number of implementations of lex/yacc-like systems. E.g PLY (http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) is a python implementation. The important point is that you should spend your time working on your *language* and not on inventing yet-another (badly written) lexer/parser. The world already has waaay too many of those (including one I wrote myself :-).

Answer (score 0):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/index.html).[Qi](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/quick_start.html) would be my first choice.

> Spirit.Qi is designed to be a practical parsing tool. The ability to generate a fully-working parser from a formal EBNF specification inlined in C++ significantly reduces development time. Programmers typically approach parsing using ad hoc hacks with primitive tools such as scanf. Even regular-expression libraries (such as boost regex) or scanners (such as Boost tokenizer) do not scale well when we need to write more elaborate parsers. Attempting to write even a moderately-complex parser using these tools leads to code that is hard to understand and maintain.

The Qi tutorials even finish by implementing a parser for an XMLish language; writing a grammar for CSS should be considerably easier.

Comment: One world of caution: brings compilers to their knees! You want the parser proper to be in a single translation unit, and on its own, so as to recompile it as few times as possible. Better yet: being able to cut in into several pieces, each in their TU.